# Hide top of WebView

Tags: android, webview, hide, area

I'm dealing with a webview that's displaying a web page with a search bar at the top that I want to hide. Is there some way to make the top 50 px or so go away without using css?

Comment: Persistent topbar or does it go away with scrolling?

Comment: Try this post, should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901408/in-android-how-to-display-one-view-as-overlay-on-top-of-another-view

Answer (score 0):

You could just put a colored rectangle view on top of that part of the webview (depending if there is scrolling or not)

Comment: So how do you put a view "above" another view?