# How can I show Overlay when Incomming call in Android

Tags: java, android, overlay, call

I want to make like this (red area)

[image]

Now I do this. (BroadcastReceiver, PhoneStateListener, etc...)
show Toast. (ignore 'is null')

[image]

But I don't know how to Show Overlay when RINGING and hide when IDLE (Or connected).
When I show Activity, It shows when calling is over.

How can I do that?

Code is like this

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
   Context context;
   Intent intent;

   public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
       super();
       this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
       switch (state) {
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
               // Hide popup
               break;
           case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
               // Show popup
               break;
           default:

               break;
       }
   }
  }
```

Comment: share your code snippet where you are stuck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901408/how-would-i-display-one-view-as-an-overlay-of-another

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom `Toast` and a `BroadcastReceiver`(as you rightly mentioned) There is a very good blogpost on how to customise a `Toast` in here:
http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/customiozing-toast-in-android.html